# What does it mean to be analytic on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis

For example, what does it mean for $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ to be analytic on $[-1,1]$? For $x \in (-1,1)$ I assume that it means there exists an interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ such that the Taylor series for $f$ converges to $f$ for every $z \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ But what about for $x= \pm 1$? Does it mean that there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $\pm 1$ where $U$ is open in $[-1,1]$ (but not in $\mathbb{R}$), like a half open interval $(1-\delta,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually an analytic function $f$ should be defined on an open set.  $f$ is analytic at $p$ if the Taylor series for $f$ centred at $p$ converges to $f$ in an open set containing $p$.  So here $f$ is analytic at each point of the compact set $[-1,1]$.  But it's actually defined on a larger set, not just on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: In definition 2.3 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6102.pdf   they define restricted analytic functions to be those $f$ such that the restriction to $[-1,1]^k$ is analytic and $f$ is identically zero outside of $[-1,1]^k$. Given what you've said I don't see how to make sense of "the restriction of $f$ to $[-1,1]^k$ is analytic" as an analytic function cannot vanish on  an open set

Comment: I do think it's a typo and they meant the open interval; look up the notion of subanalyticity